# Run an SQL Query With a DateTime Parameter from Excel 2010

Tags: sql, oracle, excel

I am using ODBC connection Excel 2010, I know we can set up parameter in MS Query by adding [Blah Blah] and would add `?` in actual query.

But I don't know how to do a parameter for datatime with to_date.

Here is my where clause.

```
where ("R"."TIME_STAMP">=TO_DATE ('03-02-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
   AND "R"."TIME_STAMP"<=TO_DATE ('09-02-2013 23:59:59', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

I am not sure what Info I need to here, but here is data type of time_stamp field.

```
SQL> desc tablet
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -----------------------
 TIME_STAMP                                         DATE
```

Comment: Please provide the Oracle stored procedure you're trying to connect to.  The WHERE clause above does not accept parameters.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more what info you need? I am using excel ODBC connection which takes me to Microsoft Query where I can connect takes and stuff.

Comment: Oh-oh... you in trouble again bcs not providing enough info to help you... You are too vague. Can only suggest using Between operator and truncate your dates to compare. Add TRUNC(your_date), which will cut off the time portions unless you need this.

Comment: I am unclear which info I need to provide here. I need all the info for my date `HH:MM:SS`

Comment: @ExactaBox part of query I posted is actual query without parameters. I need help to add parameters so user can change date in some cell example A2 and query will update automatically.

Comment: @Mowgli-Why do you need a parameter? How will you use that parameter, in what program? Post that program... There is no parameters in your example. You do not necessarily need to always insert time portion for your dates etc...

Comment: I need parameter so instead of manually entering date in query, with parameter I can just link parameter to cell and user can enter datetime in excel cell A2 or something and it will update query result automatically.

Comment: @Art I already have parameter for one field in where clause but that is not date data type it is just number so it was easy, but date and time is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just preparing a SQL query and sending it to Oracle.  I thought you were calling an Oracle stored procedure.

Your where clause should look like:

```
where ("R"."TIME_STAMP" between ? and ?)
```

and in Excel, you need a cell to input the date or date/time (assume it is `A1`), and then another cell with the formula `=TEXT(A1, "MM-DD-yyyy hh:mm:ss")`.  This is the cell to link to in MS Query.  Repeat for the second parameter.

Comment: You're the guy asking for help.  If you want people to respond, you need to tell them what error you got or what the problem is.  Saying "it didn't work" won't get your solution.

Comment: I am sorry, it was rude, I am just all different possibility format. your solution kind of worked but it didn't show data for correct dates, it showed all the data from row 1 to last data in DB.

Comment: I can't really say I was "busy" but I was busy finding solution by playing with your code, but I was really doing that, that's what I just posted mini comment.

Comment: I found the solution, I totally removed `TO_DATE ('03-02-2013 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` and only left `?` and I entered the datetime in format I needed `02/02/2013 07:20:23` Thanks if you update your answer. I will mark your answer as solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use a text cell in excel to store the date as `dd Mmm YYYY` (e.g. 02 Feb 2014).

Use the parameters option (?) in MSQuery to reference the text cell(s).

```
where ("R"."TIME_STAMP" between ? and ?)
```